# insert HTML into bootstrap-table (wenzhixin) build a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-table

I have a table generated using the [table from data method](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/13/) with bootstrap tables.

Is there any way I can get html inserted into the cell from my json data array

html:

```
        <table
            id="bootstrap-table"
            data-pagination="true"
            data-show-export="true"
            >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-switchable="false">Delivery #</th>
            <th data-field="created_at" data-sortable="true">Created</th>
            <th data-field="progress" data-sortable="true">Progress</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
```

js:

```
//bs-table options
$table.bootstrapTable({
    data: dataJson,
});
```

My aim is to inject the following HTML into the progress data-field while somehow using the percentage value in there to set the progress bar width.

```
<div class="progress">                                                                                        
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:100%"></div>                                                                                     
</div>
```

Alternatively, any other suggestions on how to get a progress bar into my table would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that any code that is included in the JSON renders as HTML... so quite simple to get this working! i.e.

```
{
"id":460000000,
"progress":"<div class=\"progress progress-margin\"><div class=\"progress-bar\" style=\"width:61%\"><\/div><\/div>"
}
```